# POIs and Direction Path in Open Layer Map

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayer 3 Map, I want to add following two similar feature of google map in  open layer map.

- **"Search Near by Places"**: POIs(Near by Restaurant, Church , School etc) on map.
- **"Direction service"**: Show direction in map between two points with direction steps.

Please help me to achieve these feature.

Thanks

Comment: Google's terms don't allow Google data to be shown on a non-Google map, but there are alternative sources of data.
You could use Overpass to return features in the area and use vector styling to show those you interested in, e.g. sport facilities https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137726/how-to-highlight-table-tennis-places-in-openlayers  For directions there are several alternative routing APIs  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257354/how-to-find-route-between-two-latlong-in-openlayers-latest-version

Comment: Hi Mike, I am not using google in openlayer map, I just wanted to use same feature in OpenLayer Map,Is there any way to show near by POIs in open Layer map.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to get that information from somewhere.  Overpass is one option for getting POIs.  There are several options for directions.